# How to use between and greater than in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table name:tax
       slab1    slab2    tax
        0        10000   0
        10001    50000   10
        50001    100000  20
        100001    0      30
```

Here 0 represents infinity.

my table is like this.I have to find the tax of 60000.I dont't know how to use between and greater than in sql together.

```
I tried like this:
$query="SELECT * FROM taxsettings 
        where $liable2 between tax.slab1 and tax.slab2 
           or $liable2 > tax.slab1";
```

$liable2 is the amount.
 any one can say how insert infinity value to db table

Comment: ---(I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. If $liable2 is between slab1 and slab2 it already has to be greater than slab1. And by using an `or` your `greater than` statement renders the between statement useless.)--- this is WRONG see next comment as to why.

Comment: @X.L.Ant huh, I did not know that. Thank you! Great, X.L.Ant deleted his comment.

What he said was that `BETWEEN` is not `> AND <` but `=> AND <=`

Comment: Generally for the "infinity" value people just use a higher than conceivably possible value like 99999999999 (or maybe the max for the data type)... BTW are `taxsettings` and `tax` two different tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM taxsettings 
WHERE 60000 (between slab1  and  slab2) or 60000>slab2
```

Comment: its ok. i also how to check whether the value is greater than 100001 in the same line of code.

Comment: While this code may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation will go a long way towards helping current and future readers understand your answer even better.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
"SELECT * FROM taxsettings 
        where $liable2 between case when tax.slab1=0 then $liable2 else tax.slab1 end  and case when tax.slab2 =0 then $liable2 else tax.slab2 end;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM taxsettings 
    WHERE  $liable2 >= slab1  and  
    $liable2 <= 
    CASE when slab2 = 0 then 1000000000000 --some big number a upper limit
    else slab2 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the largest slab1 value thats smaller than the value you're checking ($liable2) :

```
SELECT Tax
FROM taxsettings
WHERE slab1 <= $liable2
ORDER By slab1 desc
Limit 1
```